# Using the less-than equal-to (<=) in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

How can I rephrase this line of code in the proper ERB syntax?

```
 <% if current_user.age == "13" and @example.thing >= 1 %>
 <h1>say this</h1>
 <% elsif current_user.age == "13" and @example.thing == 0 %>
 <h1>hello world</h1>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are checking the same condition in your `elsif` that you did in your `if` like this, you should be able to move the `elsif` functionality inside the initial `if`

```
<% if current_user.age == "13"%>
  <h1><%= @example.thing >= 1 ? "say this" : "Hello World" %></h1>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Important to note that this isn't *exactly* the same. Your `elsif` handles 0 specifically, whereas mine prints "Hello World" in situations where `@example.thing` is *non-positive*, which is very distinct from 0. So mine will also print "Hello World" in cases where `@example.thing` is negative, yours would show nothing at all

Comment: now that Im trying it, it is causing another error `undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass`